# Enviar mensagem para cliente quando houver alteração no sistema com Websocket Ratchet PHP?

Tags: php, websocket, longpolling

Olá, fiz um WebSocket PHP com o Ratchet.

O server.php está da seguinte forma:

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Chat;

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8000
    );

    $server->run();
```

E a classe Chat() está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from === $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Até aí ok. Porém, eu tenho a tabela notificações no mysql, e eu gostaria de enviar ao cliente uma mensagem sempre que existir um novo registro, no caso fazer o cliente ficar "escutando" o servidor até que o mesmo envie um alerta. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer controlar o cliente?

Comment: Não sei se seria isso. Por exemplo, tenho a tabela notificações, quero dar um $client->send() somente quando a tabela possuir novos registros. Eu teria que ficar fazendo um loop executando a query toda hora dentro do Websocket?

Comment: As alterações na tabela são feitas por um dos usuários que estão conectados na room? Se sim, assim que um usuário executar uma ação que insira um novo registro na tabela notificações, você pode fazer um select e enviar para os usuários logados na room como mensagem

Comment: Recomendo dar uma olhadinha https://github.com/pmill/react-chat
Achei péssima a documentação do Ratchet e acabei encontrando esse reac-chat